# filtro do mat-table funcionando apenas no primeiro caractere

Tags: angular, filter

Olá

Estou com um problema na configuração de um filtro de pesquisa no mat-table (angular 2.x).

A tabela está sendo populada através de uma requisição conforme:

```
getAllLabs() {
    this.param = this.route.snapshot.params['param'];
    this.service.getAllResults().subscribe(res => {
      this.listResults = new MatTableDataSource(res[this.param]);
    })
  }
```

O filtro de pesquisa é chamado diretamente no input:

```
 <mat-form-field fxLayout="row" class="formSearch" appearance="outline">
   <mat-icon matPrefix>search</mat-icon>
   <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Pesquisar...">
 </mat-form-field>
```

```
 applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.listResults.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
```

O retorno, tanto do listResults quanto do filterValue estão todos ok, mas o filtro só funciona com a primeira letra digitada no input de pesquisa.

Por exemplo:
O listResults é um array de cidades e está populado da seguinte forma:

```
 ['São Paulo', 'São Carlos', 'Rio de Janeiro']
```

**Exemplo 1:**
Ao digitar a letra 'S' o filter busca as cidades de São Paulo e São Carlos, porém, ao digitar "Sã" (ou "Sa") ele não retorna nenhum filter, como se não houvesse correspondência;

**Exemplo 2:**
Ao digitar a letra "R" o filter retorna a cidade do Rio de Janeiro, mas ao digitar a próxima letra (i), o filtro não encontra correspondência.

Ou seja, a partir do segundo caractere digitado, o filtro do mat-table não encontra resultados.

Não há qualquer erro no console e nem nos retornos das variáveis.
O que posso estar fazendo errado? Alguma sugestão?

---

**EDIT**

Segue comportamento em vídeo para explicar melhor.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/15yhewRby9ipLMiiAJmrSsc4FpBRRbIBp/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar [two-way data binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding-) em seu input e aplicar o filtro utilizando a variável, assim:

```
<input matInput name="search" [(ngModel)]="term" (keyup)="applyFilter()" placeholder="Pesquisar...">
```

```
term: string = "";

applyFilter()
{
    this.listResults.filter = this.term.trim().toLowerCase();
    console.log(this.listResults.filteredData);
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Um gif para exemplificar o filtro desta resposta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Persistiu o mesmo comportamento, amigo. Editei a pergunta e coloquei o link de um pequeno vídeo que gravei pra explicar melhor o comportamento que ta ocorrendo.

Comment: @jb1102 Tente verificar a forma de criação do `MatTableDataSource`, talvez o problema seja esse.

Comment: justamente @ivansnpmaster! o problema estava em como a minha tabela era preenchida na requisição ao servidor, reescrevi o método e deu certo! obrigado.